# Installing .net core hosting bundle crashes all existing application-pools on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-7.5

I have an existing IIS 7.5 installation containing many web-applications. I'm trying to deploy a new asp.net core web application. So I've installed the .NET Core Hosting Bundle. I've restarted the server, but now all the existing web-applications does not work as I get an http 503 service unavailable error. I can see that whenever one of the web-applications are accessed the associated application-pool crashes and stops.
In the eventviewer I get a series of warnings with the message:
"A listener channel for protocol 'http' in worker process '5204' serving application pool 'ASP.NET v4.0' reported a listener channel failure. The data field contains the error number."
and then finally an Error with the message:
 "Application pool 'ASP.NET v4.0' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool."
I've tried with the 2.2.2 hosting bundle and also with the new 3.0.0 preview bundle and the same thing happens. Whenever I uninstall the hosting bundle the original web-applications work again (doesn't require restart).
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using separate app pool(s) for your ASP.NET Core apps?

Comment: @ChrisPratt it is very bad that Microsoft decided the modules must be installed at server level and apply to all pools (no matter what pool you use).

Comment: Check if you installed VC++ 2015 runtime, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle

Comment: The modules are there, but they're not utilized unless the Web.config calls for them. However, doing something like attempting to host an ASP.NET Core app in the same pool as a regular ASP.NET app is very likely going to blow up in a big way.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yes I have separate pools. But just installing the hosting bundle crashes all the other application pools and as soon as I uninstall the hosting bundle they work again

Comment: @LexLi Microsoft's docs says that if the server has Internet access the installer will download it if needed, but I can try to install it manually and see if that works

Comment: Installing the VC++ 2015 runtime made no difference.

Comment: What kind of modules are in use by the ASP.NET apps? Anything exceptional or that stands out from a run of the mill type installation? I know I had a weird issue once trying to run New Relic on a server that had both 32-bit and 64-bit apps in IIS. It would crash one or the other depending on which architecture of New Relic was installed. Not really related to your case here; just to point out that there can be weird conflicts. You might consider simply deploying your ASP.NET Core apps to a different server.

Comment: Nothing special, very vanilla.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: it's unresolved

Comment: I've just tried installing the lastest hosting runtime on the same old IIS and now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now tried installing the latest version of the hosting bundle and it now works

Comment: what version did you use as "the latest"? It seems that currently I'm having similar problem

Comment: I used 3.0.0 preview 9.19424.4

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I installed the update "Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB2999226)" and repair  VC++ 2015 
(vc_redist.x64.exe /repair)

Comment: (KB2999226) is already installed and a repair of the newly installed VC++ 2015 made no difference

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I fixed it installing the VC++ 2015 both (x32 and x64) from the next link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685